# how do I access a BlockingQueue from either Swing or the Console?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

Whether it's from a GUI or Console, how would either interact with `Consumer`?  Should I simply expose `consume` as public, or perhaps package-private?  That seems like it's stepping into a minefield.

Consumer:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.State;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Title> queue;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Title> queue, ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.objectOutputStream = objectOutputStream;
    }

    private void consume() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Title title = queue.take();
        title.setState(State.x);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            consume();
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            //exit?
        }
    }
}
```

the service:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;

public class ProducerConsumerService implements Executor {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProducerConsumerService.class.getName());
    private final BlockingQueue<Title> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
    private Producer producer = null;
    private Consumer consumer = null;

    public void ProducerConsumerService() {
    }

    public void produce() {
    }

    public void consume() {
    }

    public void startService() throws IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
        String host = props.getProperty("server");
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        producer = new Producer(queue, objectInputStream);
        consumer = new Consumer(queue, objectOutputStream);
        new Thread((Runnable) producer).start();
        new Thread((Runnable) consumer).start();
        log.info("started...");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        new Thread(command).start();
    }
}
```

Or, alternately, do I add methods in the service to access the `BlockingQueue`?  However, doing so seems to obviate the need for the `Consumer` class itself.

What's the correct usage of these three classes by an outside class, either a Console or Swing interface?

reference:

http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem

Comment: I usually connect the producer and consumer at construction time with a mediator...which might just be the BlockingQueue, or it might be something more substantial. As you scale up, a good design will allow you to also scale up producers and consumers independently.

Comment: so the Swing class can just `take` and `put` to the `BlockingQueue` directly from the service instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My concern with the following solution:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;

public class ProducerConsumerService implements Executor {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProducerConsumerService.class.getName());
    private final BlockingQueue<Title> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
    private Producer producer = null;
    private Consumer consumer = null;
    private Title title = null;

    public void ProducerConsumerService() {
    }

    public Title produce() throws InterruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        producer.produce();
        title = queue.take();
        consumer.consume(title);
        return title;
    }

    public void startService() throws IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
        String host = props.getProperty("server");
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        producer = new Producer(queue, objectInputStream);
        consumer = new Consumer(queue, objectOutputStream);
        new Thread((Runnable) producer).start();
        new Thread((Runnable) consumer).start();
        log.info("started...");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        new Thread(command).start();
    }
}
```

is that it breaks encapsulation by exposing too much of `Produceer` and `Consumer` through the `produce()` method in the service.